# Wicket Wizard Dropdown modelValue will not update

Tags: java, wicket

I am creating a ListView with a list of Priced Services. Each priced service has a list of different terms which is a DropDownChoice. The problem is that the value for Term don`t get updated when I select various values in the dropdownlist. This is a wizard, so I am trying to update the wizard with the correct Term before clicking "next" (The Wizard-object has a ProductOrder-object which has a Term-object).

Thanks,
Terje

```
    public ServiceSelectionStep(final NewSubscriptionWizard wizard) {

    final ListView<PricedService> serviceChoiceList = new ListView<PricedService>(
            "serviceList", 
            wizard.getCompanyPriceModel().getPricedServices()) {

        protected void populateItem(ListItem<PricedService> item) {
            final PricedService service = item.getModel().getObject();
            // Adding labels to the list.
            addPricedServiceLabels(item, service);

            DropDownChoice<Term> termsDropDown = new DropDownChoice<Term>(
                    "term", 
                    new PropertyModel<Term>(wizard.getProductOrder(), "term"),
                    service.getTerms(), 
                    new ChoiceRenderer<Term>("description"));

            item.add(termsDropDown);
        }
    };
    add(serviceChoiceList);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using an AJAX callback. Check the "Drop Down Choice Example" on Wicket Examples.

http://www.wicket-library.com/wicket-examples/ajax/

[This](http://www.wicket-library.com/wicket-examples/ajax/wicket/bookmarkable/org.apache.wicket.examples.source.SourcesPage?5&SourcesPage_class=org.apache.wicket.examples.ajax.builtin.ChoicePage) is the important file that shows you how to do this using the correct models.

Answer (score 0):

Try targeting the termsDropDown in the AjaxFormComponentUpdatingBehavior.

```
termsDropDown.add(new AjaxFormComponentUpdatingBehavior("onchange") {

            @Override
            protected void onUpdate(AjaxRequestTarget target) {

                wizard.getProductOrder().setService(service);
                System.out.println("Chosen term: " + wizard.getProductOrder().getTerm());

                target.addComponent(termsDropDown); 

            }
        });
        item.add(termsDropDown);
```